# How to query filter in django without multiple occurrences

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

ParentModel: 'just' sits there

ChildModel: has a foreign key to ParentModel

`ParentModel.objects.filter(childmodel__in=ChildModel.objects.all())` gives multiple occurrences of ParentModel.

How do I query all ParentModels that have at least one ChildModel that's referring to it? And without multiple occurrences...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it right...

```
ParentModel.objects.filter(childmodel__in=ChildModel.objects.all()).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to avoid using `childmodel__in=ChildModel.objects.all()` if the number of `ChildModel` objects is large. This will generate SQL with all `ChildModel` id's enumerated in a list, possibly creating a huge SQL query.

If you can use [Django 1.1 with aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation) support, you could do something like:

```
ParentModel.objects.annotate(num_children=Count('child')).filter(num_children__gte=1)
```

which should generate better SQL.